# Does Apple reveal its iOS review wait time?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

The site [appreviewtimes.com](http://appreviewtimes.com/) croudsources reports from iOS developers to figure out the current average iOS/Mac apps review time:

[image]

**Does apple reveal any information about the current review queue size?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't say anything about the size of the queue, but they do give this information on review times [on the developer website](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/) (emphasis mine):

> Review times may vary by app. On average, **50% of apps are reviewed in 24 hours** and over **90% are reviewed in 48 hours**. If your submission is incomplete, review times may be further delayed or your app may be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides no information on the queue size, just that it may take at least 7 days for your app to be reviewed.

Appreviewtimes.com is a very good site for estimated review times, I have found it to be very accurate.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if weekends are included in the count?

Comment: Yes, thankfully Apple also reviews apps on the weekend!

Comment: Thanks. With the lack of any official source, this is probably as good as it gets.